# How to set Tax and Shipping fees in Laravel Paypal package

Tags: php, paypal, laravel-5.5

Recently i'm working on a laravel project which i choose to use `srmklive/laravel-paypal` as my paypal payment gateway plugin, but i found that i cannot add Tax and shipping fees, i have read the readme.doc multiple time and also check the paypal documentation, but i still confused on how to add the tax and shipping fees.

Did any one know how to add these data when setExpresssCheckout?

here is my code:

```
$provider = new ExpressCheckout;
            $provider = PayPal::setProvider('express_checkout');

            $itemsArr = $data = [];

// add items
            foreach ($order->orderProduct as $order_product) {
              array_push($itemsArr, [
                  'name' => $order_product->product->name,
                  'price' => $order_product->price,
                  'qty' => $order_product->quantity
              ]);
            }

            // add shipping fees
            array_push($itemsArr, [
              'name' => "Shipping Method : ".$order->shipping_method,
              'price' => $order->shipping_fees,
              'qty' => 1
            ]);
            $data["items"] = $itemsArr;

            $data['invoice_id'] = 1;
            $data['invoice_description'] = "Order #1 Invoice";
            $data['return_url'] = url('/payment/success');
            $data['cancel_url'] = url('/cart');

            $total = 0;
            foreach($data['items'] as $item) {
                $total += $item['price']*$item['qty'];
            }

            $data['total'] = $total;

            $options = [
              'BRANDNAME' => 'Ulife',
              'LOGOIMG' => asset("images\ulifelanding.png"),
              'CHANNELTYPE' => 'Merchant'
            ];

            $response = $provider->setCurrency('MYR')->addOptions($options)->setExpressCheckout($data);
```

Ps: i also asked on the github, but still confused.

Comment: I'm also trying to figure out this problem. Were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: im having the same problem , i think package has harded code this

'NOSHIPPING'                     => 1,

Answer (score 0):

I don't know who still needs an answer for this question, but I share ("srmklive/paypal": "~1.0").

1. go to ExpressCheckout.php and go to setExpressCheckout add this :

> 'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'           => $data['total']+$data['tax'],
>
> 'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT'        => $data['tax'],

2. and you checkoutData put now:

> 'tax'=>xx

3. call your provider with addOptions:
   example:

> $options = [
> 'BRANDNAME' => 'MyBrand',
> 'LOGOIMG' => 'https://example.com/mylogo.png',
> 'CHANNELTYPE' => 'Merchant',
> ];

$provider->addOptions($options)->setExpressCheckout($checkoutData)